# Command "maintenance:install" is not defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, nextcloud

I had an image of [Nextcloud](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker) **v. 14** in my production environment (AWS ECS).
On September 22, the service stopped because the volume was full.
Expanding the CPU, the error that appears to me is:

> The "maintenance: install" command is not defined.

I have not made any modifications in to the cluster. This error started when the CPU reached the limit. I tried to update the version, but the error is the same. I still haven't found the solution.

Comment: The maintenance:install command is only available for instances that are not set up yet. 

You should check your nextcloud.log (in the data directory) and the web server's error log.

Answer (score 3):

Today I experienced the same issue. Once you run `occ maintanance:install` it disappears. It is likely this is the way it has been designed. My solution was to delete entire nextcloud directory, drop all tables in the DB and redo all again.